# What are the best up-to-date secure approaches of generating pseudorandom number in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, security, cryptography, randomness, random

I am thinking about creating a lottery with more than one winner and one round for users. Please don't consider usual 'commit-reveal' scheme. However, person can claim rewards on their own at the end of the lottery.

So, generation of pseudorandom number is essential.

 I'm looking forward for approaches without 3d party involvement.
 I would be very grateful to all answers!

Comment: Yes, I saw this too. I'm interested in the most effective/secure approaches, many answers for question are outdated for 2023, from my point of view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short:

There's no "**safe**" way to generate pseudo-random numbers in smart contracts if those numbers are used for critical functions. The only plausible solution (for now) is an **Oracle**.

In your case, creating a pseudo-random number in a smart contract for something like a lottery is a bit like trying to keep a secret everyone can figure out. Since everything on the blockchain is transparent, anyone with enough know-how can predict the number. So you need to account for that.

If you can implement the lottery system such that knowing the results of the pseudo-random-number generating function offers no advantage, you are good. But I don't see a legit way fo accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

This question already has been **asked and answered** more than once.

If you are building a lottery, pseudorandom **is not safe**, for lotteries or gambling since it can be found or manipulated.

However, **on top of all the other solution easy to find with a simple search**, there is now a `new solution` to pseudo-randomness and *answering this now  could prevent future duplicates*:

- Since the Ethereum merge the new opcode `prevrandao` made its appearance, to replace the previous `difficulty`:

[image: solidity docs]

**Useful links:**

- [The official EIP](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4399)
- [use of prevrandao()](https://soliditydeveloper.com/prevrandao)
- [other stackoverflow possible uses and opinions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73938799/chainlink-vrf-or-randao)